# Regex pattern in JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, json

I'm trying to have a single JSON file to validate data both in front (JS) and back (PHP).
I cannot figure out how to have my pattern in a json string, PHP won't convert it.
Here's what I'd like to use (email validation):

```
'{"name":"email", "pattern":"^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$"}'
```

I suppose there's something in pattern that doesn't get treated as a string? This as it is, won't convert to an object in PHP. I shouldn't have to escape anything but I might be wrong...

thanks

Edit: Tried this as suggested in comments:

```
json_decode('{"name":"email", "pattern":"^[a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,15})$"}‌​');  ==> NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What does "PHP won't convert it" mean? What is the result in PHP? Using what code?

Comment: json_decode(mystring)

Comment: Nope. Also not a duplicate, my object structure is fine.

Comment: Your object structure yes, your syntax no. http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @deceze : jsonlint valid the answer of ljacqu. If the owner's problem persist, it's coming from another part of his code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem are the backslashes `\`. Use two to signal that there is one and it will work well:

```
{"name":"email","pattern":"^[a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,15})$"}
```

---

The above is valid JSON but will cause trouble as PHP string, because `\\` will already be interpreted as one `\` before it is passed to `json_decode()`, and we're back where we started from. As [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) kindly pointed out in the comments, this can be solved by adding four backslashes:

```
{"name":"email","pattern":"^[a-z0-9]+(\\\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\\\.[a-z]{2,15})$"}
```

Or by immediately passing the contents from `file_get_contents()` (or similar) to `json_decode()`.

Comment: There must be something else, I've tried that too. Still won't parse

Comment: json_decode('{"name":"email",  "pattern":"^[a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,15})$"}'); ==> NULL

Comment: @Eric If you're writing it as a PHP string literal (as opposed to reading it from a file, for example) you'll need an additional backslash for each backslash.

Comment: Do you mean triple backslash for a backslash ?

Comment: Indeed, \ has to be \\\\ in PHP. `{"name":"email","pattern":"^[a-z0-9]+(\\\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\\\.[a-z]{2,15})$"}` works. But the one in my post is valid JSON. I'll do a test with JavaScript and I'll update my post in a bit.

Comment: @Eric Quadruple backslash for each backslash. Tip: write the plain regex into a file, then: `var_export(json_encode(array('pattern' => file_get_contents('regex.txt'))));` This'll "reverse engineer" the valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @deceze, I hope it's OK that I've linked to your profile in my update.