# Disallowing spaces in usernames [UserFrosting/Fortress]

Tags: validation, userfrosting

How would I implement a filter to block out spaces in username (during registration)?

I've been looking at the [Fortress](https://github.com/userfrosting/fortress) documentation, and probably the `regex` option is the one to look for. But there's no documentation examples on regex, and I've been unsuccessful so far in my own efforts (including `\` escaping issues in a JSON document).

I hope this is something simple to resolve.
Thank you.

[UserFrosting 0.3.1]

Answer (score 1):

[Regex](https://github.com/userfrosting/wdvss#regex) would indeed be the best option in this case.  Have you tried:

```
"user_name" : {
    "validators" : {
        "length" : {
            "min" : 1,
            "max" : 50,
            "message" : "ACCOUNT_USER_CHAR_LIMIT"
        },
        "required" : {
            "message" : "ACCOUNT_SPECIFY_USERNAME"
        },
        "regex" : {
            "regex" : "/^[\S]*$/",
            "message" : "Username cannot contain any whitespace characters."
        }
    },
    "sanitizers" : {
        "escape" : {}
    }        
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, invalid JSON in error log and blank page as a result. I think it's the \ that needs to escaped somehow. Maybe something else. Also, you forgot a comma after "regex"? I also got "Undefined index: regex," in some of my tests. Could not get it to work.

Comment: Fixed the comma.  So the error is only on the server side code?  Or is it failing when it is translated into the Javascript rules as well?

Comment: For testing, I replaced the "user_name" entry in register.json, with your version. Register page produces a blank (white) document. In the server error log I get the following: "...register.json' could not be found, or it does not contain a valid JSON document...". The problem seems to be the \ (backslash) in the regex entry. Once I remove the backslash, the page loads. (but the script does not work as intended of course)

Comment: So it looks the problem is that the schema needs to be recognized by both Javascript and PHP as a valid JSON document.  As you found, the `\\` is causing a problem.  Apparently you need to use _four_ backslashes to escape properly - check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25426567/2970321).